# Get multiple product images using REST API

Tags: product, magento2, api, product-images, rest-api

I'm requesting products list using the following API call `GET /V1/products`

> http://127.0.0.1/magento2github/index.php/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria%5BpageSize%5D=100000&searchCriteria%5BcurrentPage%5D=1

That gives me the following response:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1298,
      "sku": "2000315",
      "name": "testProduct",
      "attribute_set_id": 4,
      "price": 5,
      "status": 1,
      "visibility": 4,
      "type_id": "simple",
      "created_at": "2015-12-29 19:51:31",
      "updated_at": "2015-12-29 19:53:09",
      "weight": 0,
      "product_links": [],
      "options": [],
      "tier_prices": [
        {
          "customer_group_id": 0,
          "qty": 1,
          "value": 5.75
        },
        {
          "customer_group_id": 1,
          "qty": 1,
          "value": 5.75
        },
        {
          "customer_group_id": 26,
          "qty": 1,
          "value": 5.35
        },
        {
          "customer_group_id": 27,
          "qty": 1,
          "value": 5.75
        }
      ],
      "custom_attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "description",
          "value": "<p>Some description about this item comes here...</p>"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "image",
          "value": "/w/i/wijn1_back_1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "small_image",
          "value": "/w/i/wijn1_back_1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
          "value": "/w/i/wijn1_back_1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "options_container",
          "value": "container2"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "required_options",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "has_options",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "url_key",
          "value": "testproduct"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "swatch_image",
          "value": "/w/i/wijn1_back_1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
          "value": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [],
    "page_size": 100000,
    "current_page": 1
  },
  "total_count": 1
}
```

If you look at `custom_attributes` array you will only see the base image. How can I retrieve the other images configured in Magento2?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to iterate over products and retrieve images using `GET /V1/products/:sku/media`, there does not seem to be a way without multiple requests.

Comment: thanks, must have looked over that operation. Can confirm I get both images now. One more api call isn't an issue!

Comment: @emp does the json data helps to add images via default api in magento 2.3 ? hope it has to be base64 encode